# Change android theme from cordova config.xml

Tags: android, xml, cordova, ionic-framework

At my company we are using Ionic Framework and Cordova to create our mobile app, and upon starting the design of the app, we encountered an issue with the Android theme and how to set it without touching the AndroidManifest generated by Ionic build command.

Everywhere I look it is recommended to implement any customization from the config.xml file and never touch the AndroidManifest, but I cant seem to find any methods regarding the Android theme.

My question to you now: Is there a way to set the android theme for the application, for example Holo Theme, from the Config.xml without changing the AndroidManifest.xml generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid touching the platforms directory, you could use a cordova [hook](https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world/blob/master/hooks/README.md).  I am pretty terrible at node, but here is something that should do the trick.  First `npm install elementtree` then create a sub folder `after_prepare` in the hooks folder.  From there stick this code into a javascript file and change YourTheme.

Honestly, this is some pretty gross code, but should give you the idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var fs = require( "fs" );
var et = require('elementtree');
var rootdir = process.argv[2];
console.log(rootdir);
fs.open(rootdir + '/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml', 'r+',
    function (err, fd)  {
        if (err) {
            exitError(err);
        }
        fs.stat(rootdir + '/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml', getStats);

        function getStats(error, stats) {
            if (error) {
                exitError(error);
            }
            var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
            fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, fileRead);
        }

        function fileRead(error, bytes, buf) {
            var data = buf.toString("utf8", 0, buf.length);
            var androidXML = et.parse(data);
            var root = androidXML.getroot();
            var activityTag = root.find("application/activity");
            activityTag.attrib["android:theme"] = "@style/YourTheme";
            var outputBuffer = new Buffer(et.tostring(root), "utf-8");
            console.log(outputBuffer.toString());
            fs.closeSync(fd);
            fs.open(rootdir + '/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml', 'w', writeFile);
            function writeFile(error, fd) {
                if (error) {
                    exitError(error);
                }
                fs.write(fd, outputBuffer, 0, outputBuffer.length, 0, function( errw, written, str) {
                    if (errw) {
                        exitError(errw);
                    }
                    console.log('file written');
                    fs.close(fd);
                });
            }

        }
    });

function exitError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I thought about using a hook, but shouldn't there be something we can add to the config.xml file to change things like this? Considering the fact that phonegap build had a feature to write custom xml that would be merged with the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Again, this can be done via hooks.  After poking around a bit more, it seems like this file adds some nice features (including themes): https://github.com/djett41/generator-ionic/blob/master/templates/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js

Comment: Oh very nice, i poked around a bit with the generator but didn't see these hooks. It opens doors to new configuration possibilities. Thanks for the help !

Comment: For anyone using @laughingpine's linked hook. It works well, but make sure you check to make sure that the Activity name in preferenceMappingData actually matches up against the activity listed in the node: manifest>application>activity in AndroidManifest.xml. Ours was called MainActivity so we needed to change 4 of the preferenceMappingData xpath expressions to match up.

Comment: I have created one style i.e custom_theme inside style.xml. So how I can add  it dynamically while adding platform ?

Answer (score 14):

You can do this now without any third party plugin since 6.3.0. Just add this to the config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:label='@string/activity_name']" mode="merge">
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"></activity>
    </edit-config>
</platform>
```

and for me it was also neccessary to add 'xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ' to the widget tag

```
<widget id="de.bestellkind.restaurant" version="1.0.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Comment: It says "AAPT: error: resource android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoActionBar not found.". Does it work with Ionic 4?

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm late, but `cordova-custom-config` plugin made just to "update platform configuration files based on preferences and config-file data defined in config.xml."

for example:

1. install the [cordova-custom-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config) plugin: `cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config --save`
2. Config.xml: `<preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:theme" value="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>`

This will add the attribute "android:theme" to your AndroidManfiset --> application --> activity with the value: `@android:style/Theme.Holo`.

Comment: How to add custom theme instead of android default theme ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Header Color plugin:

Install the plugin:

`$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-headercolor
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/header-color`

Add configuration to config.xml

`<preference name="HeaderColor" value="#becb29" />`

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/header-color/